# SQL server testing referential integrity

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database with 2K+ tables. I need to check if a row in one table is being used by any other table (all relations are up and running with IDs). Only idea I have is

```
BEGIN TRY
 BEGIN TRANSACTION
  DELETE dbo.LC147_PlanProracuna WHERE PlanProracunaID = 47
  SELECT 1
 ROLLBACK
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 SELECT 0
END CATCH
```

How do I check if a row in table A is being used in any other table in database or (even better) how does SQL SERVER checks referential integrity (and how can I use the same method if it is even possible)?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about finding dependency between tables then you can use [`sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb630351%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) as well as
[`sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb677185%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for this purpose.

An example would be below which will return the entities in the specified database that refer to the `LC147_PlanProracuna` table.

```
SELECT referencing_schema_name, 
referencing_entity_name, 
referencing_id, 
referencing_class_desc, 
is_caller_dependent
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('DB_NAME.dbo.LC147_PlanProracuna', 'OBJECT');
```

You may as well find [This Article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/04/sql-server-get-the-list-of-object-dependencies-sp_depends-and-information_schema-routines-and-sys-dm_sql_referencing_entities/) helpful.

Comment: It isnt the thing im looking for coz it is showing objects. I need to check if a specific row in a table A is being referenced (i have the Identity/PK of that row) in any other table. In my example, i need to check if row with ID=47 is being referenced

Comment: To check that, you can do a `INNER JOIN` with the other table saying `from LC147_PlanProracuna t1 join other_table t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID`

Comment: Dude, with 2k tables in DB that is kinda a long query that can/will be calculated over a few sec. Secondly, with adding new tables into DB that query would be obsolete, and it is not viable for Stored procedures. If there is no 'clean and easy' way to do it, ill make a dynamic query that will do that with system tables and then execute code with ID of specific row/rows

Comment: @GustavKlimt, with `clean and easy way` if you mean any built in procedure/function then NO. Internally how SQL Server DB engine determines that I have no idea about and neither it's published any document/white paper. Other then what I have pointed in my answer/comment; yes a dynamic query to check through the system views will as well do but that would be fast, can't sure off.